# Why is it allowed to std::move a const reference?

Tags: c++

Consider this example:

```
#include <vector>
void addRow(std::vector<std::vector<double>>& matrix, const std::vector<double>& row) {
    matrix.push_back(std::move(row));
}
```

I would've expected issues with `std::move` and a `const &` as `std::move` basically invalidates that reference since it's contents are moved and it is set to a clean state, and this is the exact behavior `const` must prevent.

This was compiled using:
`g++ -std=c++20 -Ofast  *.cpp -o test` with no warnings or errors and runs fine.

I've looked at other posts:
[Move construction from const reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745275/move-construction-from-const-reference)
-> apparently this didn't use to work

[Const reference VS move semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642357/const-reference-vs-move-semantics)  -> no answer

[Why can we use `std::move` on a `const` object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28595117/why-can-we-use-stdmove-on-a-const-object) -> apparently it works on a const as well, though that's not concerning

What's concerning about the reference, is it's invalidating an object it's promising not to modify.

The mostly frustrating thing about my post being labeled a duplicate is that I linked the 'duplicate' and explicitly stated it didn't answer my question, also expressing the reason why. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't invalidate anything, it silently falls back to copying (unless the class has an unusual move constructor accepting `const T &&`).

Comment: Do you have a source for this @HolyBlackCat ? I was expecting some sort of compilation error, which I would've preferred to silent behavior.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move It doesn't remove constness.

Comment: You can test it yourself on a custom class that logs the constructor calls. It natually follows from `std::move` not removing constness (just adding `&&`). Then, because `const T &&` isn't convertible to `T &&` (that would drop constness) but is convertible to `const T &`, the latter ends up being used.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat So if I'm following you, it's cast to an rvalue reference (reference to temp), and the `const` takes precedence so it is converted to a `const` lvalue reference (reference to object with duration). What exactly does this change?

Comment: What I'm saying is, you have a copy and a move constructor: `T(const T &)` and `T(T &&)`. The second one can't be used since there's no conversion from `const T &&` to `T &&`. So the first one is used.

Comment: I see. Why exactly is there an rvalue reference involved for a move constructor? Intuitively, I'd think it'd be a regular lvalue reference.

Comment: If you run clang-tidy, it will notify you that moving const reference does nothing but copying.

Comment: `std::move()` cast lvalue to rvalue then `T(T &&)` would work.

Comment: What is the purpose of the rvalue here @LouisGo ? I don't ever really understand r value references

Comment: Then you need to maybe try to research rvalue references.

Comment: Its purpose is to allow moves. You can't move from lvalues, by definition.

Comment: I believe you could move a non-const lvalue @tkausl . In my program, I went through (removing the `const` in the function in the post), and it seems to move it correctly.

Comment: `I went through, and it seems to move it correctly.` Of course it does, because you pass it through `std::move`. If you didn't, it wouldn't move, because it doesn't move a lvalue.

Comment: Are you saying that an rvalue reference to `my_vector.pushback(a)` where `a` is the rvalue reference, would be moved?

Comment: No, you'd still need a `std::move`.

Comment: I believe this may be out of my scope, since I'm not quite understanding rvalue references @tkausl and you aren't really explaining them.

Comment: `std::move` does **not** move anything, it was just a lot shorter than `std::permission_granted_to_suck_out_the_objects_innards_and_leave_behind_an_empty_husk`.  It treats the named object as an rvalue.  If the object was a `const` lvalue, it'll be treated as a `const` rvalue.  Still `const`.

Comment: What does treating it as an rvalue do @Eljay ? I don't really get that. I've read about 'perfect forwarding' and understand it may be related to that.

Comment: Treating the named variable as an rvalue gives permission to steal all of the object's internal state, leaving it in a valid-but-unspecified state (suitable for re-assignment or destruction).

Comment: But couldn't you also do that to an lvalue? @Eljay

Comment: That's **how** you do that to an lvalue.

Comment: Why is it not permitted to just do it to the lvalue itself @Eljay?

Comment: For example, if I were to perform `std::move` on a `std:vector<int>&` that is not `const`? @Eljay

Comment: @HolyBlackCat what would happen if the class accepted `const &&`? I'm really trying to understand this.

Comment: @user8393252 Then that constructor would be preferred over any other, but it's unclear what you would do in it, since moving normally modifies the source object.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat why is `std::move` not able to modify the source if it's just a regular reference `&`. I don't really see the purpose of an rvalue, nor do I understand what it really is.

Comment: An **rvalue** is an object that is about to become unused, as such the compiler can optimize the operation to just *move* the internal state of the about-to-go-away value into the the other object.  If that **rvalue** is `const`, then the compiler is **not** allowed to *move* the internal state to the other object, and instead has to *copy* the internal state.

Comment: So if it's an _lvalue_, it cannot move the internal state @Eljay ? Someone else told me that you could, and `std::move` could take a `&` parameter, but `&&` makes it more versatile.

Comment: You should ask that *someone* what they're talking about.

Comment: So you're saying that you could not steal the contents of a `&` and a `&&` makes it possible? It was in a thread in another question I asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74958711/what-is-the-purpose-of-an-rvalue-reference-for-stdmove

Comment: Here is a direct quote (they received 2 upvotes) : "In the case of std::move they could have used & instead of &&, but then std::move would fail to compile on a rvalue, which might be annoying in generic code. It is not useful to intentionally pass a rvalue to std::move. But a forwarding reference accepts both lvalues and rvalues. "

Comment: You are conflating *forwarding references* with *rvalue references*.  Those are two different things (albeit with similar syntax), used in different contexts.